# Changing Mouse Cursor to a sprite div

Tags: javascript, css

For example, we usually use:

`style.cursor="url("+url here+"),auto";`

The issue is, this creates a HTTP request if the image is not already rendered. Is it possible to set the mouse cursor style to a, for example:

`<div class="sprite mouseimageclasshere"></div>`

instead of it having to be a direct link to an image? This way, there is no unnecessary HTTP requests sent. (Of course once the user has loaded the sprite image already).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can have a [base64-encoded data-URI](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/) wherever you have an URL.

There are some border cases (size limits in old IEs, can't have certain file types), but images are ok in general. 
It's possible that mouse cursors are one of the exceptions to the rule, it should be worth a try. (If you put up a fiddle and a cursor file, it's easier for us to provide an example.)

Comment: I tried the base 64 option. It still sends a http request though, but it says 0 bytes sent. Is this just something that shows up in Chromes console log? (the request isn't requesting my server though, right? It's grabbing the base64 URI?)

If so, I will mark yours as the best answer. This is a nice and workable alternative.

Comment: @NiCkNewman: it shouldn't send a request, no. (For one thing, there's not even a server name in sight.) The nearest example I have here is a background-image in a CSS file, and the console lists the request, but lists "(data)" in the status column and "from cache" as size and content, even with "disable cache" checked.

Comment: Thanks Ulrich, appreciate the help! Marked.